# How to make a webpage vertically responsive using CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin, web-frontend

I am making a webpage which has a nav-menu, a hero section which will be after navbar and I want to show this hero section in the remaining space of (100vh - height of navbar) and also, I want to make it vertically responsive (i.e., when user seeing in different device or resizing the browser height. I am getting a proper layout in iPhone 12 layout (i.e., 375 x 675) but when I go to another layout, like iPhone 12 pro, I am getting a layout which I don't want according to my expectation.

HTML and CSS code For Hero Section That I want to show on the remaining (100vh - height of navbar) -->

```css
  html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 320px;
  .header {
    background-color: aqua;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 4.5rem);
    #the height of the navbar is 4.5rem
  }
  .hero-about-container {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .hero-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .hero-title {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .summary {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  }
  .read-more {
    background-color: hsl(5, 85%, 63%);
    padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.3rem;
    color: white;
    border-color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <header class="header" id="header">
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 765px)" srcset="./assets/images/image-web-3-desktop.jpg">
      <img class="hero-image" src="./assets/images/image-web-3-mobile.jpg" alt="hero-image">
    </picture>
    <div class="hero-about-container">
      <h1 class="hero-title">The Bright <br> Future of Web <br> 3.0?</h1>
      <div class="hero-details">
        <p class="summary">We dive into the next evolution of the web that claims to put the power of the platforms back into the hands of the people. But is it really fulfilling its promise?</p>
        <button type="button" class="read-more">Read More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</section>
```

root font size is default and height of navbar is 4.5rem and I have taken a 1rem padding on my whole page.

I want this layout in every device or close to it
[image: Iphone SE]

but I am getting a marging below after "Read more" in other device
[image: Iphone 12 pro]

This is what I am getting in my normal browser.
[image: edge browser]

[image]

I will be adding more content on my webpage, but this particular section should cover the remaining (100vh - navbar height)
I just want to understand how to make a webpage responsive vertically as I am not able to make a webpage responsive which is boggling my mind. I just started 2 months back so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use media query and change font size according to screen and set that parent div min height to (100vh-nav height). change the image height or font-size to fill the empty margin.

Comment: _"but I am getting a marging below after "Read more" in other device"_ - you are getting blank space, because your header element _is_ as high as you wanted it to be, only its actual content doesn't match that height ... It is really rather unclear how you _want_ this to behave in that situation.

Answer (score -1):

**You should use media queries for responsiveness**

The media query in CSS is used to create a responsive web design to make a user-friendly website

- For Mobile devices: 320px-480px.
- For Tablets or iPad: 480px - 768px.
- For Laptop or small-size screen: 768px -1024px.
- For Desktop or large-size screen: 1024px -1200px.
- For Extra-large size device: 1200px and more

Like this, you can add media queries for any device that you want